# Bounds on eigenvalues of the sum of an arbitrary matrix and a positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a matrix $A$ which has no special properties. Can we say bound the eigenvalues of $A + P$ where $P \succ 0$ positive definite? What if $P$ is semi definite?

It seems to me like the real part of the eigenvalues of $A$ should be shifted more positive by some amount. I'm not sure how to show this though. I know of Weyl's theorem, but it only applies when both matrices are symmetric.

I want to show something like: $\Re (\lambda_{i}(A + P))> \Re (\lambda_{-}(A))$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda_{i}(A + P)$. Here, $\lambda_{-}(A)$ denotes the eigenvalue of $A$ which has the most negative real part. In other words, the eigenvalues are all bounded to one side of the complex plane defined by $\lambda_{-}(A)$.

I have no clue where to start in showing this.

Comment: There is no such general formula, unless $A$ (or $P$) has additional properties. The eigenvalues of sums of general matrices do not have very nice properties in terms of the eigenvalues of the terms in the sum, except in some very special cases. I would say that this is an XY problem. What would like to obtain such a result in the first place?

Comment: The motivation is basically showing that the matrix in the end remains invertible: i.e. if A has eigenvalues which have positive real parts, and I add a positive (semi) definite matrix to it, the real part of the eigenvalues still remain positive and therefore the sum is still guaranteed invertible. What do you mean XY problem?

Comment: Invertibility has nothing to do with the real part of the eigenvalues, it just means that no eigenvalue is equal to zero. So, in the end, $A$ has some properties it seems. Then, you frame your question the way you just mentioned; i.e. invertibility of a sum of matrices. Otherwise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem